# Good idea to control LCD contrast using a microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, lcd

In a commercial product, would it be a good idea to control LCD contrast using a microcontroller?

The LCD is to be installed in a vehicle and is to withstand temperature changes. I am concerned if the temperature changes would cause the LCD to be become unreadable.

The microcontroller i am using to control LCD does not have a DAC so I will be using a digital pot or external DAC.

Comment: You really need to add more detail about the product and how it's used to know if it's worthwhile or not.

Comment: What are other parts of the projects? Will you add a microcontroller just to control the LCD's contrast or is there already one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most examples I've seen the contrast control line has been adjusted automatically by a thermistor: -

[image]

This picture came from [here](http://www.newhavendisplay.com/tempcomp.html) - it describes how the circuit works and shows its output compared to the typical theoretical requirements for a typical LCD.

You can of course use a micro but you'd be copying most of the circuit above, reading the analogue value into the micro thru an ADC pin then outputting possibly a PWM signal that can be low pass filtered then fed to the LCD. Can't see the need to over complicate it really. Stick with "simple". Simple is usually best!

[Here's](http://www.oppod.com/services/notes-info-59.html) another page that uses the same circuit. [Here](http://www.vishay.com/resistors-non-linear/resistor-thermistor-netsim/) is a computational tool that can help - slightly different circuit but the tool, I'd imagine, will give you values.